# Pre-fill structure with chars and its array

Tags: c, struct

Easy question...I know a lot of the values ahead of time, and need to add others later, but why doesn't this compile on the line "direc[i] = {L"Jim",L"Smith"};" where I know the values?

```
struct NARRAY
{
TCHAR *sFName;
TCHAR *sLName;
};

void main()
{
struct NARRAY direc[1000];

DWORD i = 0;

direc[i].sFName = calloc(512,sizeof(TCHAR));
direc[i].sLName = calloc(512,sizeof(TCHAR));

direc[i] = {L"Jim",L"Smith"};

}
```

Comment: You might want to tag your question with the programming language it is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use structure/array initialization, which is only allowed when declaring variables. You have to initialize each member by itself:

```
direct[i].sFname = L"Jim";
direct[i].sLname = L"Smith";
```

Of course, if you dynamically allocate these members for some entries in the array, and statically (like in my example above) for some entries, you really have no way of knowing which was allocated dynamically or not, which will lead to problems when you come to free those pointers. You can use [`strdup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y471khhc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (or rather, `_tcsdup` for `TCHAR`) then:

```
direct[i].sFname = _tcsdup(L"Jim");
direct[i].sLname = _tcsdup(L"Smith");
```

Answer (score 1):

Classical C doesn't have struct literals. You can only use that syntax when initializing a variable, i.e. as partof its definition.

However, C99 introduced [compound literals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html), which would allow you to write it like so:

```
direc[i] = ((struct NARRAY) { L"Jim", L"Smith" });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a function such as `memcpy` or `strncpy` to copy your data to the allocated memory.

```
memcpy(direc[i].sFName, "Jim", 3);
direct[i].sFName[3] = '\0';
```